# Docker security scan detects vulnerability in gradle 7.4.1

Tags: security, gradle, jackson-databind

Creating a docker image with gradle 7.4.1 triggers the security scan which shows vulnerability CVE-2020-36518. How can this particular jar file within the gradle package be updated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would just reject the security issue, explaining that it is not possible to exploit the vulnerability as the Gradle build runs isolated on controlled input, and is not accessible by any potential attackers.

(Assuming this is the case, of cause, and you don't have a custom Gradle plugin that reads untrusted JSON documents using Jackson from the Gradle classpath. But even then, all you are risking is a denial-of-service on the build.)

Fiddling around with jar files in external tools could easily lead to problems hard to debug later. But if you like, you could create an [issue](https://github.com/gradle/gradle/issues) for them, asking if they could bump the Jackson version to avoid unnecessary noise from security scans like this. There is an example of that [here](https://github.com/gradle/gradle/issues/15707).